# Namibia: Traveling visa free to collect ill relative?

Tags: visas, namibia

I would normally call the embassy in question to ask this, but they are closed for the weekend and I am in a slight hurry, so I am hoping someone here might be able to shed some light.

My father has just had a heart attack in Namibia, and as I live in the United States I am the closest person in the world to Africa in my family. I would like to go to the hospital he is in to collect him and take him back to Australia.

Although this is not a vacation, would this fall under the "holiday" exemption for having a visa? I will not be working when I am there.

I will likely not have a return ticket booked on arrival, because I do not know how or when I would be leaving. I also do not know how long he will need to be in the hospital before he can leave, and I do not know which airline he would be flying to leave (He will already have onward travel plans on a flexible ticket, so I assume when he is healthy he will be able to use that ticket). I suspect this would be on the order of days or weeks, not the three month limit on visaless entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your nationality is on the [exempt list](http://www.namibia.org.za/consular-service/), which includes Australia, US, UK and Canada, you are fine for "Visiting Friends or Relatives":

[image]

It's unfortunate that you have to go under such circumstances, Namibia is a beautiful country. Assuming you are a prosperous-looking Westerner I doubt you will have any questions about onward travel and tickets. The government has been doing some money grab things so you might not want to volunteer that you are taking your Dad out, just that you are visiting when he is ill.

Comment: I did not end up going to Namibia but the person that did used this advice and had zero issues.